# Winapi Shell_NotifyIcon - Duplicated icons in Notification Area Icons window

Tags: visual-c++-2010, winapi

I´m working on a C++ application that creates an icon in notification area, with a baloon tip. When user clicks the baloon, the icon is being removed using Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, &nid), just as MSDN instructs to do.

The problem is that the notification icon leaves the tray, but it remains in the Notification Area Icons window (that window which opens when you click the Customize option in windows 7/8´s tray). Then, if the user restart the program, the icon will be duplicated many times as the program can be restarted, even if the computer is being restarted.

I googled about and I found out that removig some registry keys, the cache can be cleaned, but explorer.exe needs to be restarted... but this is not an option I want to put in pratice, for many reasons.

My questions are:
- Have any of you guys seen this before?
- Is there some alternative to Shell_NotifyIcon (assuming the possibility that the usage of this being the problem, once I´m not too much experienced in Winapi);
- Is there any way to force "cache cleanup" in notification area window without restarting explorer.exe?

For those who can help, my gratitude in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the NIM_DELETE isn't actually working. Check you have the structure initialized correctly as it is quite a confusing API.

Comment: It is working to remove from tray, but the icon remais in the Customize windows.

Comment: It is supposed to stay in the Customize dialog. That way the user knows that the icon appeared in the first place and can decide the icon's behavior whenever it appears again. Just being listed in the Customize dialog SHOULD NOT prevent your app from running again, or displaying the same icon again.  If it is not working correctly, or is being displayed duplicate times, then you must be doing something fundamentally wrong in your tray icon management code.

Comment: As for alternatives, there are the [`IUserNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774424.aspx) and [`IUserNotification2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774412.aspx) interfaces, but they are just wrappers that use `Shell_NotifyIcon()` internally.

Comment: I´ll try IUserNotification2 intead. Thanks Remy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, IUserNotification2 worked great and the problem is solved.

I wrote a new notification class based on [Notifu´s](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/code.html) examples, using [IUserNotification2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/bb774412%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [IQueryContinue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/bb761367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IUserNotificationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Thanks to all for helping.